# Android: AlarmManager called my Broadcast Receiver even though the trigger time not reached yet

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am having trouble with alarm manager and the broadcast. This is my code which schedule the task in an hour.

```
var preference = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (Application.Context);
        var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService (Application.AlarmService);  
        var intent = new Intent (Application.Context, typeof(ScheduleUsageLogReceiver));
        var schedule = new LogSchedule (1);
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer (typeof(LogSchedule));

        if (preference.Contains (ScheduleUsageLogReceiver.SHARE_PREFERENCE_USAGE_NAME))
            return; 

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, schedule);
            var json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            var editor = preference.Edit ();
            editor.PutString (ScheduleUsageLogReceiver.SHARE_PREFERENCE_USAGE_NAME, json);
            editor.Commit ();
        }

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast (Application.Context, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.Set (AlarmType.Rtc, schedule.NumberMillisecondToLog, pendingIntent);
```

The Broadcast Receiver which receiving the schedule is

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter (new string[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionShutdown, "com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF", Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted } )]
public class ScheduleUsageLogReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public const string SHARE_PREFERENCE_USAGE_NAME = "ScheduleUsageLogReceiver"; 

    public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText (context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show ();}}
```

I have a bootComplete action and shutdown action but I do a breakpoint but the intent didn't contain these action so I don't think this is the problem.

I have checked that the trigger time is 3600000 but don't know why it trigger immediately when I compiled and run the application.

Comment: Because **3600000** is **Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00** in GMT which is already passed. `alarmManager.Set (AlarmType.Rtc, schedule.NumberMillisecondToLog, pendingIntent);` here the 2nd parameter is time at which alarm to be fired not the difference.

Comment: Oh I see.. If I want to trigger in an hour , I should be add 1 hour to the current time in millisecond

Comment: Yup you are right. You need to add 1 hour mili's to the current time.

Comment: Thanks I will try that..

Comment: Okay try and let know for issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating PendingIntent of an alarm for past time it will be fired immediately. Check and confirm that the time you are providing is not a passed/current time.